# How to queue pods in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, bitbucket

I am new to Kubernetes and I am facing some issues.

The project codebase in bitbucket and in each commit, there are pipelines in bitbucket which build a pod in the Kubernetes cluster. So the pods do some tasks and terminate after the task got completed. When the commits are high cluster fails due to a large number of pods. So I am trying to find a solution to queue it in the Kubernetes cluster so the pods will use all the resources of my cluster after the termination of the pods it will run the other pods in the queue and so on. Any help?

Comment: If you want all jobs to get executed and getting failed because of large number of pod. You need to use cluster autoscaler which will add/remove worker node. 

https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler

Comment: Can you use a task queue like RabbitMQ, with some long-running workers managed by a Deployment?  That would let you control how much work gets done at a time, and decouples you from Kubernetes some.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [pod resource requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) so that when you create a pod and requirements cannot be satisfied, scheduler will put it in pending state and schedule it as soon as there are available resources.

The only downfall of this solution is that it does not guarantee that pods will be created in the same order as api request sent to create them.